# How to access Sqllite DB installed in android from web portal through USB

Tags: java, android, spring, sqlite, jakarta-ee

We have android app and web portal developed in java for a client, `sqllite` db is installed in android app. I want to do *offline sync*, in order to do that i am connecting android device to PC through `USB`. Is possible to access the sqllite db installed in android device from web portal?

I really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think you can directly access from usb as the database will be stored in apllications private memory not in sdcard,but you can export your database via code in your app (just for viewing purpose) and upload the file to your server

```
public class ExportDB {
   final static String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "yourdatabase";
   public static void exportDB(Context context){
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        FileChannel source=null;
        FileChannel destination=null;
        String currentDBPath = "/data/"+ "your.package.name" +"/databases/"+SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
        String backupDBPath = SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
        File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
        File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
        try {
            source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
            source.close();
            destination.close();
            Toast.makeText(context, "DB Exported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```